# Considering getting IR remote, will it work with things like VLC?

Tags: hardware, 17.10, vlc

So I was digging around today and found my IR receiver for my old Sony Vaio desktop PC. It was only the receiver as I had lost the actual remote years ago but now I am considering getting a replacement remote.

If I get it will it automatically detect which button is which? In other words, if I open, say, VLC, to play the next episode of *Alias* and I press the pause button on my remote will it all sync up?

The model number for the receiver is pcva -ir5u and the remote is, I think, rm-gp5u.

Comment: There is a program called lirc which is used for IR stuff in Linux. You mostly can't expect it to work out of the box. You may have to bind the buttons with specific actions yourself. So you'll need to do some reverse engineering stuff.

Comment: Is it harder than qjoypad?

Comment: I don't have experience with qjoypad. It is medium to hard, depending on how standardised your remote codes are, which affects how easily `lirc` can detect them automatically for you. If that part gets over easily, then it should be smooth sailing.

Comment: I guess I meant as easy as qjoypad, like is it a GUI?

Comment: No. Command Line. See this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LIRC and http://www.lirc.org/. By the way, it has configuration files shared by others. So, if you find your remote already on the database, then you could simply grab that file.

Comment: That's odd, I looked on the very large list of cog files and there was nada on the remote.

Comment: Rite... I'm btw I'm surprised to see a hello kitty remote. That's quite odd

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called [LIRC](http://www.lirc.org/) which is used for IR stuff in Linux. You mostly can't expect it to work out of the box. You may have to bind the buttons with specific actions yourself. So you'll need to do some reverse engineering stuff.

It is medium to hard, depending on how standardised your remote codes are, which affects how easily `lirc` can detect them automatically for you. If that part gets over easily, then it should be smooth sailing.

It is a command line tool. To get started, go here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LIRC

It has configuration files shared by others. So, if you find your remote already on the database, then you could simply grab that file. Otherwise, you'll have to play your buttons one by one, grab the codes with your IR Receiver (of course, with the help of LIRC) and make the config file for your remote.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be on the long extensive list